# How to obtain screenshot from videofile?

Tags: android, screenshot

I tried to obtain the image from video with help MediaMetadataRetriever. I get a screenshot of only the first seconds of the video? Why?

I tried

```
retriever.getFrameAtTime(System.currentTimeMillis())
retriever.getFrameAtTime(1111)
```

Result is the same!!!

---

How obtain 2 seconds of screnshot? 3,4 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try getting the thumbnail of the video:

Below is the code:

```
int id = **"The Video's ID"**
ImageView iv = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
iv.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

Let me know if this post was of any help.

Answer (score 0):

one more way to get thumbnail:

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: How obtain 2 seconds of screnshot?